# Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor

i have an meteor built pretty huge application im getting this error

Meteor.userId can only be invoked in method calls. Use this.userId in publish functions

i'm not able to figure out from where this error is coming the path/line of error shown by METEOR console doesn't  really exists

It show error in this file

```
packages/settlin:astronomy-meta-behavior/lib/behavior/behavior.js
```

Which is not existing in my project

I'm really getting annoyed

Can any one let me know what might cause this issue

If i search Meteor.userId() in entire project will get some 30 occurrences

any help will be appreciated

Comment: This is a package that your project uses, either directly or indirectly. Can you include your publication function (and the relevant model definition)?

Comment: how my project can use some lib indirectly?? any idea ??

Comment: Dependency of a dependency.

Comment: ohh ok thanks will check